# How do I make the minimizing of a website window more dynamic, and not clunky?

Tags: html, css

By more dynamic, I don't mean responsiveness or mobile opt. What I want is for a horizontal scroll bar to appear every time the window is minimized and all elements cant fit in the new-smaller window size. This isn't the best for user experience but its a temporary fix for the lack of mobile opt/responsiveness. I got it to work(somewhat) but have ran into some problems.
As you can see here:
https://jsfiddle.net/ruegnear/

There are no photos or anything in this JSFiddle because its in my file directory, but the problem is still visible noticeable.

When it is minimized (made narrower vertically) the column that was on the right disappears (the column with the navy blue circles and text) and is replaced with white empty space. When it it minimized (height < width) the other way, the elements such as the nav bar gets completely compressed and looks unprofessional..

I have tried:

```
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: hidden;
```

but that just hides the vertical scrolling which is impractical in this case.

I have also tried:

```
min-width: 1000px;
```

and that allows for the horizontal scroll bar to appear if the window goes below that width/res in the first place, but still causes the aforementioned problems.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know where you can exactly find it but i thought you could fix that with jquery

http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/default.asp maybe this can help because it is responsive.